# Receiving "Signature did not match. String to sign used was..." when trying to access Azure blob with SAS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

After using the `@azure/storage-blob` NPM package to generate an SAS token for a blob and then appending that to the end of the `blobUrl`, I am receiving the following error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:1ef69362-901e-0040-7d73-2d98d5000000
Time:2021-04-09T19:07:19.0571601Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r

2021-04-09T19:08:30Z
/blob/[process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT]/[container]/[blobName]



2020-06-12
b





</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I have compared these values against the parameters supplied in the `sasOptions` and they match perfectly. My relevant Node.js code is as follows:

```
let blobUrl = 
`https://${process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/${container}/${blobName}`;

const sasOptions = {
    containerName: containerClient.containerName,
    blobName: blobName,
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse('r')
};

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
    process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT, 
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
);

const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

blobUrl += sasToken;
```

Comment: After reviewing my question, I realized that my issue may have been caused by using the connection string to create the `sharedKeyCredential`. However, if I use the account key, the error message changes to: "The specified resource does not exist.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! The issues were:

1. I did indeed need to use the account key instead of the connection string, and
2. When appending the `sasToken` to the `blobUrl`, I needed to add `?`... *facepalm*.

Final code is as follows:

```
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
await blockBlobClient.upload(data, data.length, { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: contentType }});
let blobUrl = `https://${process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/${container}/${blobName}`;

const sasOptions = {
    containerName: containerClient.containerName,
    blobName: blobName,
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse('r'),
    protocol: SASProtocol.https
};

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT, process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY);

const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

blobUrl += `?${sasToken}`;
```